# How to draw a region of double integral in LaTex?

Tags: diagrams

May you please help me to sketch the region of `0 < x < 1` and `1-x < y < 1-x^2`.

Comment: Use tikz to draw the lines `1-x` and `1-x^2` and look up `fill between`  on the site

Comment: Should the first range of integration, `0<y<1`, maybe be stated more directly as `0<x<1`?

Comment: Looks like people severely misunderstood what you want. It would be better if you for example draw a sketch by hand of what you want.

Comment: @Mico you are right. Sorry it was a typo on my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, pstricks, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.95,-2.95)(3,3)
\psset{arrowinset=0.15,showorigin=false, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle, linejoin=1}
\psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue, ticksize=-2pt 2pt]{->}(0,0)(-2.95,-2.95)(3,3)[$x$,-120][$y$, -120]
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Lavender, linestyle=none, algebraic]{\psplot{0}{1}{1 - x^2}\psset{linecolor=Lavender}\closepath)}
\psline(-2,3)(3,-2) 
\psparabola{-}(-3,-8)(0,1)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Answer (score 1):

Is it what You want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}

\begin{equation}
\Int_{0}^{1} \Int_{1-x}^{1-x^2}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes exacly! Thanks

Comment: @user118746 if You find my answer useful mark it as helpful, please.

Comment: You answer is useful, but I need sketching the region of double integral

Comment: You mean plot a graph?

Comment: yes, I mean graphing the region

Comment: @user118746 - Do you have some information about the properties of `f(x,y)` you wish to share?